# How to convert a html form into excel file?

Tags: javascript, excel, html, html-table, ms-office

I am making a html form and wanted to convert the form into the excel file

```html
<table style="border: 1px solid black;">
 <tr><td colspan="2"style="border: 1px solid black;"><text style="text-align:center;"><h4>A/U/S/H</h4></text></td></tr>
 <tr>
 <td rowspan="5" style="border: 1px solid black;"><h4 style="text-align:center;">code</h4></td>
 <td style="border: 1px solid black;">Ay-NIA/code of peripheral centre/ADR Number/Year</td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border: 1px solid black;">Ay-IPGT/code of peripheral centre/ADR Number/Year</td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
   Un-NIUM/code of peripheral centre/ADR Number/Year
  </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I do not use JS, but in python you have libraries for reading/writing excel files. Generally you would open the file, fill in the info and then close the file. Excel libraries provide you with a functions of the sort lib.write(row,col,data). Have you checked the existing excel libs in JS?

Comment: I haven't try anything untill now , can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_get_html http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Pleas chek the example bellow:

```html
include "simple_html_dom.php";
$table = '<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Header 1</th>
<th>Header 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>';

$html = str_get_html($table);



header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=sample.csv');

$fp = fopen("php://output", "w");

foreach($html->find('tr') as $element)
{
    $td = array();
    foreach( $element->find('th') as $row)  
    {
        $td [] = $row->plaintext;
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $td);

    $td = array();
    foreach( $element->find('td') as $row)  
    {
        $td [] = $row->plaintext;
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $td);
}


fclose($fp);
```

Comment: This using for convert html table to csv file. Excel support csv file and convert it to excel.